# Google Play Alpha and Beta testing APK version

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to use the Alpha and Beta testing mechanism in Google Play Console, my question is: Are versionCodes of APKs in Alpha and PROD related? meaning if I upload an APK with versionCode 9 to Alpha, do I have to continue in PROD with versionCode of 10? or can I upload to PROD versionCode of 6?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes they are related. Version codes should always be bigger than the .apk you uploaded before.

for example:

- current Production is 9
- to upload an Alpha it must be 10
- then you upload a new one to alpha it must be 11
- then you migrate it to beta.
- then you upload a new beta it must be 12
- then you finalise some details and going to upload to production it must be 13

but remember that version codes are different than version names.
codes are usually not user visible. Names are. So you can still make it look like a normal upgrade path to the production users.

for example:

- production 9 is named v1.0.5
- then production 13 will be named v1.0.6

and all the others you called v1.0.6.ALPHA1, v1.0.6.ALPHA2, v1.0.6.BETA1, v1.0.6.BETA2

Comment: Can I upload multiple version codes with the same version names?

Comment: yes you can do it if you want to. We do that in the place I work for different flavors. But I don't advise on doing it because user feedback is usually geared towards the version name. And a user might report a bug that was already fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer Budius

Comment: What I do not understand is how to upload a hotfix to production without affecting the version that is already in beta. The only thing I know to do would be to upload the hotfix version to production and then immediately increase the beta version code and upload that even if no other changes are made.

Comment: @hvaughan3 unfortunately that's the only option I know as well.